# Inheritance and HAS-A relationship

Tags: java, oop

Can I say that class ***House*** HAS-A class ***Animal*** even if that is not declared explicitly and can be seen only through inheritance?

```
public class Animal {}

public class Dog extends Animal {}

public class House {
    private Dog inhabitant = new Dog();
}
```

Comment: There is no need to add the major tag in the title.

Comment: you can, but does every Animal have a House?

Comment: @GoranŠtuc - Why are you looking at it in the reverse way??.. "Every house should have an animal" != "every animal should have a house". Its wrong both in composition/aggregation and inheritance..

Comment: you always check both ways when making such assumptions to verify if it makes sense. Also Animal might be abstract so that it can't be initialized, also consider making the implementations final if you don't want them to be extended
public abstract class Animal {}

public final class Dog extends Animal{} 

or if Dog can be extended, his implementation should be final since java favors immutable objects

Comment: "you always check both ways when making such assumptions to verify if it makes sense" - in both inhertitance as well as in composition/aggregation, reversing the relation doesnt make sense..

Comment: public class House {
    private Animal inhabitant = new Dog();
}
is fine BUT, all the methods declared inside Dog are not visible unless he casts it to Dog,
he should only put Animal there if the only methods his class House needs are declared inside the Animal class, and overriden/implemented inside the implementation(in this case Dog)
tl,dr:
-if he has multiple classes extending Animal and only needs the methods from Animal inside those classes, he can use it your way
-otherwise, makes no sense to cast Dog to Animal to recast it inside another method inside House to Dog

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Your class "House" Has-A Dog.
2. Every Dog Is-AN Animal.

> So, Yes, your House has an Animal.

Answer (score 5):

The **is a** relationship is expressed with *inheritance* and **has a** relationship is expressed with *aggregation*. Both inheritance and aggregation allow you to place sub-objects inside your new class.

Simple example:

[image]

**Aggregation**: is used when House has a Dog/Animal and Dog/Animal can exist without House.

Comment: the OP'e example is not that of composition but that of aggregation.. The animal/dog can exist without its parent object (House).

Comment: @TheLostMind  All of the association, aggregation and composition express the **has a** relationship.

Comment: I totally agree.. But I think the OP should not consider this example as the one that uses/shows Composition..

Comment: @TheLostMind you are right I edited my answer based on relationship. The image i posted shows principle of `is-a` and `has-a`

Answer (score 2):

It's more a question about semantics, there's nothing wrong in saying House has an Animal since Dog is an Animal

But reference 'inhabitant' in house can only point to a Dog instance. So, it's better to say House has a Dog. It will be more align with [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).

Answer (score 1):

You can't say that class House HAS-A class Animal. You could say an instance of class House has an instance of class Animal (or Dog).

Answer (score 1):

One of the advantages of Object-Oriented programming language is code reuse. There are two ways we can do code reuse either by implementation of **inheritance (IS-A relationship)**, or **[aggregation (HAS-A relationship)](http://www.studytonight.com/java/aggregation.php)**. Although the compiler and Java virtual machine (JVM) will do a lot of work for you when you use inheritance, you can also get at the functionality of inheritance when you use composition.

Read [Difference between IS-A and HAS-A relationships](http://guruzon.com/1/oop-concepts/inheritance-and-composition/difference-between-is-a-and-has-a-relationships-tutorial-example)

Answer (score 0):

I would say yes, because `Animal` is polymorphic for `Dog`

Answer (score 0):

> Yes, because the **House class HAS-A Dog** and **Dog IS-A (extends)
>   Animal**.....

Answer (score 0):

Is-A means it refers to inheritance or implementation using extends or implements keywords.

Has-A means  instance of one class “has a” reference to an instance of another class or another instance of same class without using any keywords.